# SlideShow and opacity Cards

Tags: flutter, dart

[image][image]

I tried to create a slideshow as you can see and it works, but after I added the code to create Cards under my SlideShow, I got this error:

I/flutter (12937): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart': Failed assertion: line 1645 pos 12: '!_debugDoingThisLayout': is not true.
I/flutter (12937): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#57317 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (12937): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '>' was called on null.

Please Help me to resolve this issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';



void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

Widget myGridItems (String gridName, String gridImage, int color1, int color2){
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color(color1),
              Color(color2),
            ],
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
          end:  new Alignment(1.0, 1.0),
        )
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Opacity(
          opacity: 0.3,
          child: Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/s1.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill)
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(child: Text("Job", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),)),
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Container(child: Icon(Icons.school, color: Colors.white)),
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Container(child: Text("Guide", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),)),
              ],
            ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
         Padding(
             padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
            child: Text(gridName, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
    ]);

    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Carousel',
      home: ImageCarousel(),
    );
  }
}

class ImageCarousel extends StatefulWidget {
  _ImageCarouselState createState() => new _ImageCarouselState();
}

class _ImageCarouselState extends State<ImageCarousel> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> animation;
  AnimationController controller;

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new AnimationController(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000), vsync: this);
    animation = new Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 18.0).animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          // the state that has changed here is the animation object’s value
        });
      });
    controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    Widget carousel = new Carousel(
      boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
      images: [
        new AssetImage('assets/s1.jpg'),
        new AssetImage('assets/s2.jpg'),
      ],
      animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    );

    Widget banner = new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20.0),
      child: new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(15.0)),
          color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: new Text(
          'Enter to learn, leave to achieve',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'fira',
            fontSize: animation.value, //18.0,
            //color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // ),
      //  ),
    );

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Kelden Bilingual Higher Institute of Professional Studies\n'
                    'Accord N° 18-1020/L/MINSUP/SG/DDES/SD-ESUP/SDA/LMN du 03/12/2018\n'
                    'Arrêté N° 078/MINEFOP/SG/DFOP/SDGSF/SACD du 13/03/2017', textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9.5,),),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[200],
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
      new Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 1, 0, 90.0),
      height: screenHeight / 2,
      child: new ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
        child: new Stack(
          children: [
            carousel,
            banner,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),

          GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            childAspectRatio: 0.9,
            crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
            children: <Widget>[
                myGridItems(gridName, gridImage, color1, color2)
            ],
          )

        ],
      ),



    );
  }

  dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your issue is in your Gridview. As soon as that's commented it our, the issue no longer happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to wrap your GridView with a Flexible so that it plays nice with the Column:

```
Flexible(
  child: GridView.count(
    primary: false,
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    childAspectRatio: 0.9,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    children: <Widget>[
      myGridItems(gridName, gridImage, Colors.blue, Colors.yellow)
    ],
  ),
)
```

Change the top of your myGridItems to this:

```
Widget myGridItems (String gridName, String gridImage, Color color1, Color color2){
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
    gradient: new LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        color1,
        color2,
      ],
      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
      end:  new Alignment(1.0, 1.0),
    )
```

Please note that I've changed the myGridItems call to:

```
myGridItems(gridName, gridImage, Colors.blue, Colors.yellow)
```

Comment: Hello @João Soares, after wrap it with a Flexible, it works, but now only my SlideShow is visible my GridView is not, and my args in this line `myGridItems(gridName, gridImage, color1, color2)` are underlined, I don't know what did I missed, please help me to check it. Thank you!

Comment: Please  @João Soares, look at the error on the image I just added.

Comment: Hello @Slimm. I tested your code with only the added Flexible widget and I can see both the SlideShow and the Gridview. Have you done any other changes?

Comment: I've added more code to explain how you can do your Colors properly. This will fix your issue.

Comment: Hello @João Soares, thank you for your help, now it's OK for the Colors but theses two variables (gridName, gridImage) are still underline. Don't know what's going wrong, I just added another image to let you see which error I got.

Comment: Replace those with the values you want.

Comment: Hello @João Soares, its works now, this is how I did: `myGridItems(gridName = "Text1", gridImage, Colors.blue, Colors.yellow)` , thanks for your assitance !